# Set Variable depending on RadioGroup button selected in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-radiogroup, android-selector

I am currently trying to get my Android app to give me a variable based on which button in a RadioGroup I have clicked. As of right now, it is only returning either null or the default value I have set no matter how I try to do the Kotlin side of the coding. The group has five buttons, and each one represents a different number. I am trying to pass that number to the next activity as a variable, but since the variables are declared within if statements, the variable is not recognized when I am trying to send it to the next activity. What I have right now is:

```
                val companyName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.companyNameText).text.toString()
                var hbv = "3"
                findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.hb).setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedId ->
                    if(checkedId == R.id.hb1) {
                        var hbv = "1"
                    }
                    if(checkedId == R.id.hb2) {
                        var hbv = "2"
                    }
                    if(checkedId == R.id.hb3) {
                        var hbv = "3"
                    }
                    if(checkedId == R.id.hb4) {
                        var hbv = "4"
                    }
                    if(checkedId == R.id.hb5) {
                        var hbv = "5"
                    }
                }
                val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("companyName", companyName)
                intent.putExtra("hbv", hbv)
```

The companyName variable is taken from an EditText field and passes without any issues. I also have 3 of these radio groups, each containing 5 buttons, but they will all work the same once I get it working. Is there an easy way to set hbv within the if statement or a way to set it equal to the text of the radio button (1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 are the text attributes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are introducing a new local `hbv` variable within each if block instead of assigning a new value to the existing one. Change your code as follows:

```
var hbv = "3"
findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.hb).setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedId ->
    if(checkedId == R.id.hb1) {
        hbv = "1"
    }
    if(checkedId == R.id.hb2) {
        hbv = "2"
    }
    if(checkedId == R.id.hb3) {
        hbv = "3"
    }
    if(checkedId == R.id.hb4) {
        hbv = "4"
    }
    if(checkedId == R.id.hb5) {
        hbv = "5"
    }
}
val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("companyName", companyName)
intent.putExtra("hbv", hbv)
```

If you create a var inside an if block, the variable only is scoped to that if block, so when you finally pass the number to the next activity, you are only passing the value of the outer `hbv` variable, which always is going to be `3`.

Comment: I tried this, but it is still just passing the default variable to the next activity. Any ideas?

Comment: @MichaelDebo Then there must be something else wrong.  How are you reading the value out of the intent in the next Activity? Are you sure that your onCheckedChange listener actually fires? You can verify this by setting a breakpoint into the listener or adding a `Log.d("TEST", "fired")` statement.

Comment: I just figured it out, I had the whole if statement block in the .setOnClickListener method and it was messing with it, moved it to just under the onCreate statement and it works great now, thanks for your help @BenjyTec

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are redeclaring the `hbv` variable inside each `if` block, which creates a new variable with a limited scope within that block. To resolve this, you should declare `hbv` outside of the `setOnCheckedChangeListener` scope and assign values to it inside the blocks without redeclaring it. Here's an updated version of your code:

```kotlin
val companyName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.companyNameText).text.toString()
var hbv = "3" // Default value

findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.hb).setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedId ->
    hbv = when (checkedId) {
        R.id.hb1 -> "1"
        R.id.hb2 -> "2"
        R.id.hb3 -> "3"
        R.id.hb4 -> "4"
        R.id.hb5 -> "5"
        else -> "3" // Default value if none of the radio buttons are selected
    }
}

val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("companyName", companyName)
intent.putExtra("hbv", hbv)
```

`hbv` is declared outside the `setOnCheckedChangeListener` in this version and updated based on the selected radio button inside the block. The when expression simplifies the logic of mapping each radio button to its corresponding value.

Comment: When using java switches together with R.id. clauses, Android Studio prints the warning "Resource IDs will be non-final" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64335374/how-to-resolve-resource-ids-will-be-non-final-in-android-gradle-plugin-version
Do you know whether this also happens with Kotlin `when` statements?

Comment: I tried this, but the app is still passing the default value of "3" to the next activity no matter what radio button I select. Any ideas?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).